# SQL SERVER - populate bridge table but eliminate some data

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, database-design

```
SELECT C.CarID, C.Make, Y.Year, M.Model , e.Engine
FROM Car C 
INNER JOIN CarYear CY ON CY.CarID = C.CarID
INNER JOIN Year y     ON y.YearID = CY.YearID
INNER JOIN Model m    ON m.CarID = C.CarID
INNER JOIN Engine e   ON e.ModelId = m.ModelID
```

I am new to SQL SERVER and please tell me how to solve this problem. I separate all tables, Car, Year, Model, Engine. I populate bridge table dbo.CarYear & dbo.ModelYear with cross join and now I have this query and result is:

```
1   Acura   1999    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   1999    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   1999    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   1999    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   1999    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   1999    MDX 3.7 L V6
1   Acura   2000    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2000    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   2000    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   2000    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2000    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2000    MDX 3.7 L V6
1   Acura   2001    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2001    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   2001    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   2001    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2001    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2001    MDX 3.7 L V6
1   Acura   2002    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2002    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   2002    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   2002    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2002    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2002    MDX 3.7 L V6
1   Acura   2003    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2012    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2012    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   2012    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   2012    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2012    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2012    MDX 3.7 L V6
1   Acura   2013    ILX 1.5 L LR ELECT/GAS
1   Acura   2013    ILX 2.0 L L4 SOHC
1   Acura   2013    ILX 2.4 L L4 DOHC
1   Acura   2013    RDX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2013    RLX 3.5 L V6
1   Acura   2013    MDX 3.7 L V6
```

as you can see, all Acura at any Year has the same models
for example, how can I eliminate some of the Car models before I populate  bridge table ,(for example Acura ILX started only from 2013)

Comment: How do you know that you want to eliminate that model? In general, how will you know which of the model combinations you *don't* want?

Comment: As a quick aside - `INNER JOIN` is fully equivalent to simplify `JOIN` so you can simply your query a bit if it suits you.

Comment: This is very hard to read.  Could you please format it in a helpful way?

Comment: well, some of the Models started late 2012 and I have a list but it is too much work if I enter all models by Year

Comment: to Hogan - I've change the format

Comment: And I changed the format back, for future reference, highlighting chunks of code or sample data in your post and clicking the `{}` button  is a fast way to format it.

Comment: Yock - yes , I know which models I want, but thing is that some of the models for instance were between 2002 & 2008 and then they stopped. if I use cross join to populate bridge table, all the all the models will have similar all the years.....I hope you understand what I am trying to do

Comment: @simon - oooh so much better!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add a WHERE clause to the query that populates your table:

```
WHERE not (c.Make='Acura' and m.Model='ILX' and y.Year=2013)
```

Comment: I read "from 2013" as "from 2013 on", but if it means only 2013 then the Year part just needs to be changed to `y.Year=2013`.  It is not clear to me which way is meant.

Comment: yes I agree it was bit confusing but AFAICU, he do not want from the year 2013 , that means no Acura ILX having 2013 as year

Comment: That seems the more likely interpretation, so I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Try thies, based on assumption

```
Select *  
From CarYear C  
             CROSS JOIN ModelYear M  

WHERE C.KEY NOT IN( Select C1.Key 
                from CarYear C1 
                        inner join ModelYear M1 
                              on C1.Key=M1.Key 
                Where C1.Name='ACura' and C1.Variant='ILX' AND M1.Year=2013 )
```

Comment: @Simon... thanks 4 pointing sorry a big typo..Actually i was writing it as ModelYear M, CarYear C where C.Key = M.Key ..

Comment: -No Problem, thanks, but I re do my question, I think I couldn't explain well- thank your time

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.CarID, C.Make, Y.Year, M.Model 
FROM Car C
JOIN CarYear CY ON CY.CarID = C.CarID
JOIN Year y ON y.YearID = CY.YearID
JOIN Model m ON m.CarID = C.CarID
GROUP BY C.CarID, C.Make, Y.Year, M.Model
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "set based" approach...where you can put items in the #DontWantEm table, instead of using lots of where AND,OR conditions.

I'm NOT saying AND,OR conditions is an invalid approach.  I'm saying this is an alternate if you need to hand-pick the "dont want" items.

```
Use Northwind
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MasterTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #MasterTable
end


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DontWantEm') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DontWantEm
end



CREATE TABLE #MasterTable 
( 
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL
)




CREATE TABLE #DontWantEm 
( 
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL
)


INSERT INTO #MasterTable ( CustomerID , OrderID , ProductID) 
select c.CustomerID , o.OrderID , od.ProductID
from 
dbo.Customers c 
join dbo.Orders o on c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID 
join dbo.[Order Details] od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID

INSERT INTO #DontWantEm ( CustomerID , OrderID , ProductID) 
select top 300 CustomerID , OrderID , ProductID
from #MasterTable


select * from #MasterTable mt
where not exists (select null from #DontWantEm dwe where
dwe.CustomerID = mt.CustomerID and dwe.OrderID = mt.OrderID and dwe.ProductID = mt.ProductID )



IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DontWantEm') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #DontWantEm
end

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MasterTable') IS NOT NULL
begin
        drop table #MasterTable
end
```